# Function gets trigger before promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise

I have this two functions, writedb is supposed to act only when uploadImages is done. I'm not getting what I'm hoping for.
The resolve shows "null" for "this.imageURL" as is predefined but is triggered before the console.log that are inside the loop which show the correct wanted information.

```
      uploadImages() {
            return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                let newImageURL = []
                for (const path of this.images){
                        fs.readFile(path,
                            async (err, data) => {  
                                const ref = st.ref(`images/${this.id}/${path.split('/').pop()}`);
                                await ref.put(data);
                                let url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
                                
                                newImageURL.push(url);
                                this.imageURL = newImageURL; 
                                console.log(this.imageURL);
                        })
                }
                resolve(console.log(this.name),
                        console.log(this.imageURL),
                        console.log('Done upload images'))
            }) 
        }
    
        writedb(){
            (() => {
                let obj = {};
                this.uploadImages().then(
                    console.log('writedb in action...'),
                    db.collection("products").doc(this.id).set(Object.assign(obj, this))
                )
            })();
        }
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can i get the promise to resolve only if the for loop is done??

Comment: Nothing stops the for loop from continuing rather than waiting on the readFile to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fs.promises` and `Promise.all` to wait for each `readFile` to resolve - and avoid the explicit Promise construction antipattern:

```
uploadImages() {
    return Promise.all(this.images.map(
        path => fs.promises.readFile(async (data) => {
            const ref = st.ref(`images/${this.id}/${path.split('/').pop()}`);
            await ref.put(data);
            return ref.getDownloadURL();
        })
    ));
}
```

Then `instance.uploadImages()` will return a Promise that resolves to an array of the data you want. `uploadImages().then((result) => { /* do stuff with result */ }).catch(handleErrors);`

Comment: Thank you ! after some though I manage to implement it and achieved the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

With CertainPerformance help I've corrected my code as follows

Thank you! After some though I finally was able to implement it and achieve the expected result.

```
uploadImages (){
        return Promise.all(this.imagespath.map(
            path => fs.promises.readFile(path)
            .then(async (data)=>{
                const ref = st.ref(`images/${this.id}/${path.split('/').pop()}`);
                await ref.put(data);
                return ref.getDownloadURL();
            })
        ))
    }

    writedb(){
        this.uploadImages()
        .then((res)=>{
            this.imageURL = res;
            
            //Firebase no toma custom objects Object.assign(obj, this)
            let obj ={} 
            Object.assign(obj, this);
            delete obj.imagespath;

            db.collection("products").doc(this.id).set(obj) 
            
        }).catch( err=>console.log(err) )
    }
```